# Macro rename sheet will not work when run using Powershell

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I have Macro that formats columns and renames the sheet(1) to Sales - sheet has different name each month e.g Sales (Jan), Sales (Feb) etc.

```
Columns("P").NumberFormat = "0.00"
Columns("Q").NumberFormat = "0.00"
Columns("R").NumberFormat = "0.00"
Columns("T").NumberFormat = "ddmmyyyy"
Columns("U").NumberFormat = "0.0"
Sheets(1).Select
Sheets(1).Name = "Sales"
```

I can run macro manually and it works fine, but when I try to use Powershell

```
$File = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\username\Clean\Sales*.xlsx'

$XLSB = 'C:\Users\username\Clean\PERSONAL.XLSB'


function Sales 
{
        $excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
        $wbPersonalXLSB = $excel.workbooks.open($XLSB)
        $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($File)
        $excel.Visible = $false
        $worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1)
        $app = $excel.Application
        $app.Run("PERSONAL.xlsb!MACRO")
        $wbPersonalXLSB.Close()
        $workbook.save()
        $workbook.close()
        $excel.Quit()
```

the formatting is changed, however the sheet name does not change.
If I remove the rename sheet, powershell works fine

```
Sheets(1).Select
Sheets(1).Name = "Sales"
```

is there something I am missing?

Comment: You don't need to select the sheet to name it

Comment: ok I removed the select sheet and again does the same thing. It works if I run macro manually, but when coupled with powershell it does not rename the sheet.

Comment: Try making Excel visible so you can see what's going on.

Comment: Also it would be worth revising your macro so it's not dependent on ActiveWorkbook - eg. you can pass in the name of the workbook you want it to operate on.

Comment: so I made it visible and to not close and quit. It has again formatted the cols but did not rename the sheet

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Any hidden sheets in your workbook?

Comment: i am using excel version 1808(Build 10730.20334). There are no hidden sheets or cols

Comment: For the record, I was not able to replicate the bug on my end with Excel version 2009. When I ran the PowerShell script and checked the sheet was renamed.

Comment: try change the last line to ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "Sales"

Comment: I will see if I can try another version to test. I have edited the last line as suggested and can run macro manually but still will not run successfully via powershell

Comment: ok so I have tested this on another machine with a different versoin of excel and it works. Will try and update my current excel version and see if it will work

Comment: The way you use Get-ChildItem (with wildcard) may well return an array of both FileInfo and DirectoryInfo objects. Yet you treat it as it it were a string containing only the path to a single file.  Check if you get only one FileInfo object and at least use `$excel.Workbooks.Open($File.FullName)`